# How To Get All Text Content from Duplicate Parent Class with Different Id?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to get all text content of a parent class detected by `addEventListener`.

The code I am using is-

```
document.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
var text = document.getElementsByClassName(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.className); 

console.log(text[0].innerText);

}, false);
```

but the problem is, where I am trying to apply the code, has same class name with different id, for example-

```
<div class="sc-EHOje gMuVTh" size="24" role="group" aria-labelledby="extraTitle_70356820.0">
```

and

```
<div class="sc-EHOje gMuVTh" size="24" role="group" aria-labelledby="extraTitle_70356820.1">
```

has same  `ClassName` (**sc-EHOje gMuVTh**) but different `id` (**extraTitle_70356820.1** and **extraTitle_70356820.0**), so if I use only `ClassName` I always get text for `id` **extraTitle_70356820.0,** even if I click for **extraTitle_70356820.1**.

How can I get all text from the class of the id I clicked when there is duplicate class name? Is there a way to incorporate the ClassName and id at the same time to get the text from parent?

Comment: Use `getElementById(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id)`? But honestly, you should consider a strategy that doesn't involve depending on the clicked element being nested three deep under the element you want to get.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined

Comment: You probably still have the `[0]` on there which is not needed since `getElementById` returns a single element...

Comment: @HereticMonkey , corrected that but I don't get any text from the parent class, also I tried to see ``console.log(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id);``, it didn't show anything either.

Comment: I would suggest to learn `.querySelectorAll()` so you can use complex CSS selectors over counting parent elements. Those allow a lot of combinations of class/attribute/id/pseudo et cetera. So `.querySelectorAll( '.sc-EHOje gMuVTh' )` would give you a nodeList of all the divs with that class you can loop over.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  ``document.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
var text = document.getElementById(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id); 
console.log(text.innerText);
}, false);``  this should be the code , right? but  it gets  : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Comment: @Mike Well, does the event target have a parent that has a parent that has a parent that has a parent?  We can't tell what you're clicking on.

Comment: @Shilly but then I will get text content for both id, I want to get the content for the  id I clicked, not both at the same time, what can I do?

Comment: Can you actually show the HTML code this is working on? I don't really see the issue without the rest of the structure. You can probably just move the click event to elsewhere or refer to the text directly with a better selector.

Comment: @Amy you are correct , because of the construction of the web page I have go like this , first I click on an area to find the third parent and then I want to get all text under that parent, problem is clas name is not unique, but it has a aria label id attached to it which is unique, so I need to incorporate that id also.

Comment: @Mike My point is we cannot see your HTML; it makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: @Mike The HTML looks like an auto generated div soup, so it's very hard to read. Since you bind the click to document directly, I cannot figure out which div is supposed to be clickable, since everything is clickable. Are you trying to find the entire rendered menu? Are you trying to find the items the customer selected? All the text seems to be inside the innermost spans, not the outer most divs, so no idea which element `event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement` will refer to. Can't you query the menu or order instead? Are you trying to scrape this website?

Comment: @Shilly if you select Fish & Chicken then click Chicken Strips you get two choices,Sauce Choice and  Side Choice, I want to get all text under a choice when i click within the box of choice, the problem is I always gey sauce choice even if I click on side choice .

Comment: @Mike I really don't understand the problem you're trying to solve. If you run this website, you should be able to get the sauce name from the order after the user has selected it. If you're trying to automate something you order often yourself, have you looked into POSTing something to the website api directly? Could you please describe what the ultimate goal is once you get the correct text string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my initial answer because I realised I think you want the uppermost parent text too as well as the text of the element you clicked on? Not sure if this answer is the correct for you but it's my take on things.

```js
//var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("sc-EHOje gMuVTh");

//for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
// classname[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
// console.log(this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.innerText);
// });
//}


// 24/09 edit

var target = "sc-EHOje gMuVTh";
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.className === target) {
    var parentElemText = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.innerText;
    console.log(parentElemText);
  }
});
```

```css
.upperMostParent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.secondUpper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.thirdUpper {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sc-EHOje.gMuVTh {
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="upperMostParent">
  Parent text content 1
  <div class="secondUpper">
    <div class="thirdUpper">
      <div class="sc-EHOje gMuVTh" size="24" role="group" aria-labelledby="extraTitle_70356820.0">Some text content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="upperMostParent">
  Parent text content 2
  <div class="secondUpper">
    <div class="thirdUpper">
      <div class="sc-EHOje gMuVTh" size="24" role="group" aria-labelledby="extraTitle_70356820.1">Some more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first code is ok, I don't want the upper most parent but the all text of the third parent of the event I clicked, below what works for me- 
``document.addEventListener('click',function (event) {



var classname = document.getElementsByClassName(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.className);

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  classname[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.innerText);
  });
}

}, false); ``  - but the problem is when I print this it comes multiple times (equals to  number of click ), do yo know why?

Comment: @Mike I have looked at your code and there are two issues:

Clicking on the innermost div the first time does not fire because the click within the for loop does not fire. It fires the second time. I think this is because the vars are being created to find the parent.parentElem etc.

Secondly, every time you click on the document, it creates another click event. So subsequent events are calling previously made click events. Hence you are getting 3 console logs, and then 4 and so on.

Comment: Can provide solution (based on the code I gave you in comment)? I am new to JS, so it is hard for me to even carry out elementary programming in JS. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mike, I have edited my code above. You can view the updates there. Your method of using the document.addEventListener('click'... is probably a more effective method. So we don't need to do the for loop anymore. We just get the parent, parent parent element of what we clicked on.